# What Happens if a Web Api Controller is hit in rapid succession?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web Api 2 (using C#) controller method running an asynchronous save (RESTful POST method). Our QA tester mashed the save button (client-side issue that was fixed, irrelevant to Q). Without a duplicate check, naturally this was saving duplicate entries to the db.

I implemented a duplicate check (duplicateCount just selects the number of items that are exactly like the item passed to post, should be 0, and it works, details irrelevant):

```
        var duplicateCount = (fooCollection.CountAsync(aggregateFilter)).Result;
        if (duplicateCount > 0) { return BadRequest(); }
```

This check works...except on the first button mash - two duplicate entries get saved, each from an individual controller hit.

So, it seems to me that the second controller hit happens before the first controller hit manages to save the item to the db, so the duplicate check passes. Is this possible?

I am more interested in the theory than the particular answer. Also, I know I can check for duplicates in the db as well, this is more of a conceptual question. The MongoDb part is really there just for completeness, I imagine it would be similar if I was doing an async save to SQL.

edit: Someone asked how I am making the call in comments. It's through RestAngular, but imo it's irrelevant because I know the controller is getting hit as many times as I hit the button. I also know for a fact that it does not create duplicates on a single hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer is "yes" - with the ability of a controller to be instantiated on any number of threads simultaneously it acts as though its multi-threaded. Your code is not "thread safe" in that its business operation requires an exclusive lock to be placed on some element of shared information (in this case the state of the database).

You could (I would not recommend) open a Mutex or a database transaction to force single thread behaviour, but your throughput would tank.

I personally don't face this very often because of my (possibly bad) insistence on all my entities having Guid primary keys and use of the SQL Merge command to either insert or update. This may be a helpful pattern (it doesn't matter how many times you send the same "message" to the controller - it will never save a duplicate).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If you can think of articles or videos that I could watch to understand it better, please link.

Comment: I can't think of any. However if I can put it more clearly; the Controller is called on a different thread than the JavaScript which calls it (in fact on another machine) therefore it is always possible for the Client application (the JavaScript) to call it faster than it can complete its task. In fact, if the call from JavaScript finds that the Controller is in the middle of doing something, IIS will spin up a new thread, and possibly in a Network Load Balanced scenario, the call from your JavaScript might run your Controller on a completely different Server.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I thought Web Api did some magic checking for principal or something.

Comment: Key thing is, the launching of your controller is governed by IIS and the NLB algorithm, the number of participating servers and the load they are under. Even if you could, it would be a really bad idea to try and stop that box of tricks doing what it was designed to do - i.e. service the Client as fast as it can using whatever resources it has at its disposal. 

Glad to have helped.